# How to request data in leaderboard format from Sequelize-Sqlite Database?

Tags: sqlite, discord.js, sequelize.js, leaderboard

I am trying to pull users and catches from a Sqlite database through Sequelize and display in a message reply a leaderboard ranked by the amount of catches.

My Sequelize Sqlite database looks like this

```
const Tags = sequelize.define('tags', {
user: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
},
catches: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0,
    allowNull: false,
},
```

I attempted to push the top 10 values in the database into an array and use the leaderboard method suggested by the discord.js guide but it returns an empty message

```
    if (commandName === 'leaderboard') {
     let board = Tags.findAll({ limit: 10, attributes: ['user', 'catches']});
     lead = []
     lead.push(board)
     console.log(lead)
     await interaction.reply(
        codeBlock(
            lead.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
                .filter(user => client.users.cache.has(user.user_id))
                .map((user, position) => `(${position + 1}) ${(user.tag)}: ${user.balance}`)
                .join("\n"),
            ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue by requesting from the database via SQLite and not Sequelize

```
const SQLite = require('better-sqlite3')
const sql = SQLite('./database.sqlite')
...

board = []
    const top10 = await sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY catches DESC LIMIT 10;").all();
    top10.map(({ user, catches }) => {
        board.push(`${user} ${catches}`)
    });
    board = board.toString();
    board = board.replace(",", "\n")

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Leaderboard")
        .setColor(0x0099FF)
        .addFields({ name: '------------------', value: board});
    return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to await `findAll` result becaase it's asynchronous:

```
let board = await Tags.findAll({ limit: 10, attributes: ['user', 'catches']});
```